# Will I have internet connection issues next day, if I unplug router at night?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I did this regularly a few years ago and used to feel like I was 'being punished' by the Interent svc provider for disabling access to my computer, because trying to re-connect the next day became a constant pain. I have the same linksys router, a comcast modem, and hi-speed broadband through their LAN. Question: who or what is at fault for lousy internet connections, slow connections, or no connections: (everybody's tech dept. blames everybody else)

The router? 10 year olds, maybe obsolete?

The modem? came with the service plan - can connect three devices on a sharedconnection.

The ISP: I read they not only even control and completely regulate bandwidth usage, but they also ration it!! (true?)

So can I safely 'pull the plug' each night for security or not?

thnx

Comment: Probably not an issue to disconnect every night.  But what specific issues were you having that were a "constant pain?"

Comment: If your broadband modem can connect three devices, it sounds like it's a router too.  (Unless the ISP actually gives you multiple IP addresses, which usually costs extra if it's offered at all.)

Answer (score 1):

> So can I safely 'pull the plug' each night for security or not?

Your security will not be increased by physically severing your Internet connection.  Any unaddressed security issues in your Linksys router, Comcast modem or any of your devices will remain unaddressed the next day when your Internet link is re-enabled, and will be exposed to exploitation while connected.

It sounds like you're creating stress and delay for yourself by disconnecting your network, so I'd advise against it.

However, pulling the plug *will* reduce power consumption.

Given, in the past it

> used to feel like I was 'being punished' by the Interent svc provider for disabling access to my computer, because trying to re-connect the next day became a constant pain.

and nothing has changed, I predict you will have Internet connection issues the next day if you unplug the router at night.